# Bivariate distribution $p(x, y) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $x = 1, \dots , n$ and $y = 1, \dots , n$. Find the marginal distributions or $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

Let two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint distribution

$$p(x, y) = \frac{1}{n^2}$$

for $x = 1, \dots, n$ and $y = 1,\dots,n$.

How would I go about finding the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$?

It seems to me that the distribution is uniform, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. Do I pick an $x$ or a $y$ or... I'm not even sure how to begin!

Comment: Yes, both marginal distributions are uniform on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the marginal distribution of $X$ in general is to compute
$$P(X = j) = \sum_k P(X=j, Y=k).$$

However, in this case we can recognize that
$$P(X = j, Y = k) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n} = P(X = j)P(Y = k)$$
which implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$.

Comment: Is it necessarily the case that both $P_X(x)$ and $P_Y(y)$ be equal to $\frac{1}{n}$? Can we not have that $P_X(x) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $P_Y(y) = 1$?

Comment: Those are not distributions.

Comment: Because

$$\sum_{x = 1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} \neq 1$$ and the same for $P_Y(y)$? I'm quite new to probability theory so I'm struggling to understand some of the concepts.

Comment: yup${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!.